# Return inside a loop: wrong in Java?

Tags: java

When coding in Python, I often use to break functions/methods by inserting `return` within loops, for example when a condition has been reached and I want to return the value. I noticed that if I do this in Java, the IDE (in this case Eclipse) doesn't seem to recognize the `return` command. For example here:

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            Node parent = e.getNode1();
            return parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse points out that *"This method must return a result of type Node"*.
Is it wrong what I am doing? Also, `parent` is declared within the `for` loop, so I cannot return it outside of the loop. One way would be to declare `parent` at the beginning (i.e. outside of the loop), but this would be quite sloppy for me to read. What is a proper way to write this?

Comment: You need to return something if `this.edges` is empty, or if `e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())` is never true.

Comment: The reason it works in python is because it inserts a return for you at the end of the function as the existing answers point out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a `return` when you're not finding the result in the loop.

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            Node parent = e.getNode1();
            return parent;
        }
    }
    return null; // ADD THIS
}
```

If you're absolutely sure this shouldn't happen and you think there shouldn't be a return here, throw an exception:

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            Node parent = e.getNode1();
            return parent;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Somebody broke the data. Send Help!");
}
```

Comment: You might add that Python's generosity here makes it that it doesn't prevent the user from him/herself, causing hard-to-find bugs (like a missing return statement or missing exception)

Comment: Well, I'll let your comment do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

You must return something if the loop ends without returning anything.

For example :

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            return e.getNode1();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What will it return if `e.getNode2()` is never `this`? All paths throughout the method must end up returning something.

Answer (score 1):

bcz you have wrapped the return in the if condition and hence the compiler is complaining.

Change your code as below

```
    protected Node getTrueParent() {
        for (Edge e : this.edges) {
            if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
                Node parent = e.getNode1();
                return parent;
            }

        }
          return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return if the if statement does not come true!

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            Node parent = e.getNode1();
            return parent;
        }
    }
    return null; // if you dont find something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node` class should have null-checks for your `Edge` list. Also, you should provide accessors/mutators for your instance fields.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Node {
    private List<Edge> edges = null;

    public List<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    public void setEdges(List<Edge> edges) {
        this.edges = edges;
    }

    protected Node getTrueParent() {
        if (getEdges() != null && !getEdges().isEmpty()) {
            for (Edge e : getEdges()) {
                if (e != null && e.getNode2() == this && !e.isPseudo()) {
                    return e.getNode1();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Node getTrueParent() {
    Node parent=null;
    for (Edge e : this.edges) {
        if (e.getNode2() == this && (!e.isPseudo())) {
            Node parent = e.getNode1();
            return parent;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```